# Server side pagination in ASP.NET Core

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, d3.js, pagination

I am trying to implement server side pagination to stagger the loading of some data I wanted loaded into the browser. This is what my controller action looks like:

```
[Route("api/meteorites")]
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetAll()
  {
      var meteories = _context.Meteorites.ToList();
      var js = new JavaScriptSerializer {MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue};
      return new ObjectResult(js.Serialize(meteories));
  }
```

This is what my Ajax request looks like:

```
var promiseWrapper = (xhr, d) => new Promise(resolve => xhr(d, (p) => resolve(p)));
Promise.all([
    promiseWrapper(d3.json, "StaticFiles/world.geojson"),
    promiseWrapper(d3.json, "api/meteorites")
]).then(resolve => {
    // Set a timer up here to ask for 500 meteorites every ten seconds
        // In your controller action, you are going to need pagination
});
```

Note that I am also using D3.js (if that makes a difference).
Thanks for anyhelp in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix my issue by updating my controller to the following:

```
[Route("api/meteorites")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetAll(int pageNumber, int pageSize)
    {
        var meteories = _context.Meteorites.OrderBy(x => x.Id).Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList();
        var js = new JavaScriptSerializer {MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue};
        return new ObjectResult(js.Serialize(meteories));
    }
```

And updating my Ajax call to the following:

```
var promiseWrapper = (xhr, d) => new Promise(resolve => xhr(d, (p) => resolve(p)));
var pageNumber = 1;
Promise.all([
    promiseWrapper(d3.json, "StaticFiles/world.geojson"),
    promiseWrapper(d3.json, "api/meteorites?pageNumber=1&pageSize=100")
]).then(resolve => {
    window.setInterval(() => {
        $.ajax({
            url: `api/meteorites?pageNumber=${pageNumber++}&pageSize=100`,
            dataType: "json",
            method: "GET"
        }).done((d) => {
            // Do something with data
        });
    }, 1000);
});
```